# Why is runaway motion predicted?

Tags: exotic-matter

The theorethical concept of negative mass brings with it some interesting calculations, like how time supposedly speeds up around great negative masses. One of those effects, fir example, shows that negative masses repulse each other, and another is called runaway motion, and it describes the gravitational interaction between positive and negative mass. With positive mass attracting and negative mass repulsing, in theory, they should push and pull each other forever, generating constant motion. However, the formula for gravitational forces: G*m1m2/r^2 shows us that if only 1 mass is negative, a repulsive force is generated, while if both were negative, an attractive force would occur. Given that, unlike how it is stated, 2 negative masses should attract one another, and differing masses should repulse. Why isn't that the case?